# Using Matlab libraries: libmat.dll and libmx.dll in managed C++ project

Tags: c++, managed, matlab-compiler

I have a project written in managed Visual C++ (Visual Studio 2010). To support creation of files in *.mat* format, I use two libraries "libmat.dll" and "libmx.dll" along with corresponding headers "mat.h" and "matrix.h". After Matlab is installed these libraries are located in Matlab directory (I use Matlab R2010a).

**Example:**

```
/* content of mat.h */
...
typedef struct MatFile_tag MATFile;
typedef MATFile* (*matOpen)(const char *, const char *);
...

private: System::Void matToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
  MATFile *pmat;
  mxArray *pa2;
  double data[2] = {0.0, 0.4};  

  matOpen openFunc;

  HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibrary(L"libmat.dll");  // not equal to NULL
  if (hLib==NULL)
  {
  //some action;
  }

  openFunc =  (matOpen)  GetProcAddress((HMODULE) hLib, "matOpen"); // not equal to NULL
  if (openFunc == NULL)  
  {
    FreeLibrary((HMODULE) hLib);
  }

  HINSTANCE mxLib = LoadLibrary(L"libmx.dll"); // not equal to NULL
  if (mxLib==NULL)
  {
    //some action   
  }

  pmat = openFunc("aaa.mat", "w");
  ...
}
```

Project compiles successfully, but in run time calling of **openFunc** command cause next error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an  indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Also I created similar project to work with above mentioned DLLs, but for unmanaged C++ and it works correcly. Looks like the problem exists only with managed C++.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using PInvoke instead of `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`? Also, `matToolStripMenuItem_Click` sounds like it is a handler for some click event. Surely you don't want to be loading and unloading the DLL on every click. A better place for that would be in the class constructor.

Comment: Thanks, Praetorian. PInvoke helped.

Comment: @rostokus I'm trying to use mat.h in VS2017. But couldn't get it to compile. `LNK2001: unresolved external symbol` error for functions in mat.h. Can you tell me which directories I have to specify in Visual Studio?